# SLComposecontroller does not disable post button for long messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, slcomposeviewcontroller

I used `SLComposerController`, but it is not disabling the post button when the character count exceeds 140 character . I want to post an URL ,image  and initial text on Twitter via my iOS application. How to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: You can shorten URL and then allow it use with your Twit text.

Comment: here is my code     [tweetSheet setInitialText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey friends! You gotta download this app %@ ",sharingURL]];
        if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
            [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"add.it"]];
        }
        [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter_ad.png"]];
      
         [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:^{
            
        }];   If i enter the character after url then that post button is not going to disable

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the user to set the correct length to send, but I think it won't send if it is too long, or give you a callback if it didn't work.

Here is what I did:

```
-(void) postOnTwitterInsideView:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                        message:(NSString *)postMessage{

    if( [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter] ){
        SLComposeViewController *twitterPost = [SLComposeViewController
                                                composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        [twitterPost setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            switch (result) {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    // tell user message was sent
                    break;

                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    // tell user message was not sent
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }];

        [twitterPost addImage:self.imagePost];
        [twitterPost setInitialText:postMessage];
        [viewController presentViewController:twitterPost 
                                     animated:YES 
                                   completion:nil];
    } else {
        // tell user he has to activate this service in his settings of iOS
    }
}
```

Comment: but still user is putting extra character then that post button should get disable and am not able to do this in my application.i have done same coding